# Set figure to not be target for next plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm working on a custom progress monitor with some graphs. I've noticed that Matlab's `waitbar` creates a figure with some special properties so that if you do

```
plot(rand(100,1));
wb = waitbar(0);
plot(rand(100,1));
```

the second plot ends up replacing the first plot and not in `wb`. **Is there a property I can set so that when I create my progress monitor and then plot something afterwards, the graph doesn't end up in my figure?**

To be clear, I'm trying to have

```
plot(rand(100,1));
temp = MyProgressBar();
plot(rand(100,1));
```

create a figure for the first plot, create a different figure in the second line, then plot a new graph in the third line.

Comment: use `figure();` before the second call to `plot`...?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a property of `temp` such that it never contains the default axis.

Comment: your problem is that your `waitbar` axes become your default axes?

Comment: Interestingly, in R2016b the plot doesn't go to the waitbar figure, but to the original figure. This is because by default the waitbar figure is created in R2016b with the `'Handlvisibility'` property set to `'callback'`, not to `'on'` (see [gnovice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185334/2586922))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To protect your progress bar figure against subsequent plotting operations, I would set the [`'HandleVisibility'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e58922) of its axes to `'off'`. That should prevent it ever becoming the current axes, thus keeping subsequent plotting commands from modifying or adding to it. It's a good practice for stand-alone figures/GUIs in general that you turn off the handle visibility of all objects (figure, uicontrols, etc.) in this way to insulate them against being modified by outside code. This is almost certainly what is done in the code for [`waitbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html).

As an additional aside, it's good practice to target your plots to a given axes by [passing the axes handle as the first argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). You also have to make sure that, if you want new plots to be added to existing plots, you use things like the [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) command first. Here's how I'd rework your example, assuming you want the two plots to appear on the same axes:

```
plot(rand(100,1));  % Creates new figure and axes
hAxes = gca;        % Get the axes handle
hold on;            % Allow subsequent plots to be added

temp = MyProgressBar();

plot(hAxes, rand(100,1));  % Will be added to the first plot axes
```